# Windows edition on non-English systems

Tags: windows, powershell, language, windows-edition

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that filters actions based on the edition of Windows (Professional, Enterprise, home, etc.).  I can use `Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption`, but according to [MS's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that "string can be localized".

I don't have non-English-language Windows systems to check against.  Can anyone confirm whether comparing against a caption string containing "Enterprise" or "Home" is sufficient across other language installs?

If it is localized, how can the edition be generally determined?

Thanks.

Comment: The string is indeed localized.  Who are you writing this script for exactly?  If you are running Windows 8+ you can change the system language of the installation of any edition of Windows 8+, except Single Language.  You should be using `OperatingSystemSKU ` and `GetProductInfo` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624565/identify-system-operating-system-by-id) the problem is a matter of finding a definitive source.  The best I could find was [this developer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358.aspx) which is not as complete as the answer in the first link would suggest it should be.

Nevertheless, the following code will return Microsoft's "official" English language name for the current running edition of Windows:

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358.aspx'

$TableText = ($page.AllElements | 
        Where-Object {$_.tagname -eq 'tbody' -and $_.innertext -like 'valuemeaning*'} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty innertext) -split "`r`n"

$CSV = $TableText | Where-Object {$_ -match '^0x0.*'} | 
        ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "^(0x0[0-9A-F]+) ",'$1,'} |
        ForEach-Object {"$([convert]::ToInt16($_.split(',')[0],16))" + ',' + $_.split(',')[-1]}

$Editions = ConvertFrom-Csv $CSV -Header 'SKU','Name'

$ThisOS = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).operatingsystemsku

$Editions | Where-Object {$_.SKU -eq $ThisOS} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Hope this helps someone.  I can modify the code if someone finds a better online source for SKU lookup.